# what is the difference between these two functions in c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
void block() {
    std::cout << "program blocked";

};
int main() {
    std::terminate_handler tst = block;
    std::set_terminate(tst);
    std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl;
    std::get_terminate()(); 
}
```

question 1 : what is the benefit of `std::terminate_handler` if I can just do `std::set_terminate(block)`

question 2 : what is the difference between `std::get_terminate()` while I can just do `std::terminate()` ?

Comment: From where does this question originally come? Where did you find the code? What does that place say about the code?

Comment: Sure, there is no benefit if that's all your doing. The benefit is that you can write `std::terminate_handler h = std::get_terminate();` to get the current handler without invoking it. Say because you want to restore it later.

Comment: ``std::terminate_handler`` is an old way as well as get_terminate ?

Comment: regarding question 2): I can't think of a reason that one would ever want to do `std::get_terminate()();`. It isn't the same as calling `std::terminate` and even calling `std::terminate` explicitly is something that one very rarely should do. `std::terminate` is there to be implicitly called by the exception handling mechanism or library functions in unrecoverable situations.

Comment: Also `block` is not a suitable terminate handler. The terminate handler shall terminate the program and never return control to the caller, but your function `block` will return after the output. So that will cause undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4):

[std::terminate_handler](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/terminate_handler) is a type, it is a function pointer to a function that that takes no arguments and returns void, it is just a pointer type, same as `int*`, you can use `std::terminate_handler` to store a pointer to any function that has this behavior.

when an exception is not caught `std::terminate()` is called which by default calls [abort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/abort), which terminates your application, but if you want to do something else (like logging) you can define a function to be called instead, and pass a pointer to that function to [std::set_terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/set_terminate) to change the behavior of `std::terminate`.

[std::get_terminate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/get_terminate) is just a handy way to get a pointer to the current function that will be called when someone calls `std::terminate()`.

a good situation where you may want to get the old handler is where you are defining your terminate handler in terms of the old terminate handler.

```
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

std::terminate_handler old_handler = nullptr;
int main() {
    old_handler = std::get_terminate(); // store old handler
    std::set_terminate([](){
        // log something to disk
        std::cerr << "custom error message!\n";
        old_handler();  // call the old handler
    });
    // calls std::temrinate() which calls our new handler
    throw std::runtime_error("error!");  
    return 0;
}
```

another situation is if you want to temporarily replace it with one of your own that does special logging, then put the old one back when your function ends.

Comment: but why would i want to store a pointer to any function since i can just use ste_terminate and give it a function and that is it why would i want to use terminate handler and get terminate ?

Comment: @maverk you absolutely can do that, did you try it?  Having a pointer type is useful for all the myriad reasons you might want to use a pointer, and for documenting the parameter type of `set_terminate`.

Comment: yes i tried giving the terminate handler a pointer to a function and that is good but it doesn't make sense because i literally do the same with set terminate

Comment: @maverk i added 2 examples of when you want to get the old handler.

Comment: @maverk There is no reason. It is just a matter of preference. Just like you can write `int return_value = 4*5; return return_value;` instead of `return 4*5;`. Sometimes code is more readable if not everything is done in one long statement and values have descriptive names. `std::terminate_handler` is just the type like `int` in my example.

Comment: you mean :

std::terminate_handler 

is an old way ? and the new way is 

std::set_terminate()

???

Comment: @maverk `terminate_handler` is a type, in the above code how would you declare `old_handler` to be called later ? you have to use `void (*old_handler)(void) = nullptr;`, i bet it now looks much cleaner with that type defined.

Comment: @maverk There is nothing old or new here. `std::terminate_handler` and `std::set_terminate` belong together. The former is just the type that the latter expects as function parameter. I don't follow where you see anything old/new here. And `std::terminate_handler` itself is just a type alias to the function pointer type mentioned in the comment above with the extra benefit that it describes what purpose the variable with this type has.

Comment: @maverk Without `std::terminate_handler`, how would you change the terminate handler temporarily, and then restore the old handler?

Comment: Prior to C++11, `auto` keyword couldn't be used to deduce the type of an object from its initializer. Therefore all long-enough typenames in std had a readable aliase. It was good practice then, and still is.

Answer (score 2):

Question 1 is the same as why do `int x = 42` then later `x+5` instead of doing just `42+5`. This is a very contrived example, but often we use intermediate variables to help make our code more readable. In your situation, either one can be acceptable.